# On Android, How can I avoid FPS drops during sensor listener setup/tear down?

Tags: android, libgdx, optimization

When I open my Android app after 5 or 10 seconds it sets up the sensor listener, during which I see clear stuttering and the FPS drops for a second to 40 instead of 60.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I am working in Android Studio with LibGDX.

Comment: Is the issue in emulator or device??

Comment: Only with device

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with Sensor Listener, but In case you mean accelerometer and other mobile phone sensonrs. You can disable them with this code:

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
config.useAccelerometer=false;
config.useCompass=false;
initialize(new yourGame(), config);
```

More information on the [LibGDX Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)

Comment: It says "sensor listener setup" in the console. I already had the Accelerometer and the Compass disabled. However it somehow solved the problem over time so I guess it's best to remove this question since it's a bit vague ?